# Error in fread {data.table} with "|" delimited file containing apostrophe

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.table

Am attempting to read in a "|" delimited file using fread() from the data.table package and am receiving an error. The error is " ' ends field 14 on line 104970 ".

Have seen older questions asking if fread() has a quote handling feature yet, have not found anything recent. Also noticed that the "sep2" feature is forthcoming, is this the feature which will solve this longstanding problem?

I can read the same data fine with read.table():

```
df.readtable<-read.table(myfile,header=F,sep="|",quote="\"",fill=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

But am unable to reproduce result with fread():

```
> require(data.table)
> df.fread<-fread(myfile,verbose=T)
Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is  0.215B
File is opened and mapped ok
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Using line 30 to detect sep (the last non blank line in the first 'autostart') ...     sep='|'
Found 17 columns
First row with 17 fields occurs on line 1 (either column names or first row of data)
Some fields on line 1 are not type character (or are empty). Treating as a data row and     using default column names.
Count of eol after first data row: 2000001
Subtracted 1 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 2000000 data rows
Type codes: 44414114444444424 (first 5 rows)
Type codes: 44444114444444424 (+middle 5 rows)
Type codes: 44444114444444424 (+last 5 rows)
Type codes: 44444114444444424 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 44444114444444424 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 17 column slots (17 - 0 NULL)
Error in fread(myfile, verbose = T) : 
' ends field 14 on line 104970 when reading data:     LW61026|CITY|STATE|000111|L|00|1800|||N|N|N|CHANEL|"CHARLIE" BOARD|2011 CITY|19911114000000|
```

Session and package info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.1    reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.3
```

Comment: Are you still having this issue? If so, could you link to a small file with which we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am meeting the same issue actually, I will turn to Pandas - as often - to deal with this kind of situation .. :(